# Log.i Log.d ecc Not working on Android Studio

Tags: android, logging, logcat

i don't know why but in my code on Android Studio when i try to use Log. It doesn't show on Android Monitor. I select all options: No filter and selected my phone. 
There is the code sample:

```
JSONObject req = new JSONObject();
try {
    req.put("username", username_login.getText().toString());
    req.put("password", password_login.getText().toString());
    req.put("path", "login");
    Log.i("request", username_login.getText() + " " + password_login.getText().toString() + " " + password_login.getText().toString().length());

    new Request(new RequestCallback() {
        @Override
        public void in_the_end(JSONObject a) {
           }}}



        }
    }).execute(req);
```

Comment: Maybe this request is not executed. Show a [mcve], please

Comment: If i use the Toast method works and this code work 100%

Comment: Try using `adb logcat` from the command line

Answer (score 0):

It will work properly it seems you have not filtered it properly

Change the settings in Log cat as mentioned in image[image]

Comment: Except there should be a debuggable application

Answer (score 0):

try changing the android phone connected. If then it works, it means there is some problem with your settings in developers option.